# Capitalize all letters after a period and a space

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to capitalize all occurrences of small letters after a period and a space using Perl. This is an example of an input:

```
...so, that's our art. the 4 of us can now have a dialog. we can have a conversation. we can speak to...
```

This is the output I'd like to see:

```
...so, that's our art. The 4 of us can now have a dialog. We can have a conversation. We can speak to...
```

I have tried multiple regexes without much success--for instance:

```
$currentLine =~ s/\.\s([a-z])/\. \u$1/g;
```

or

```
$currentLine =~ s/([\.!?]\s*)(\w)/$1\U$2/g;
```

But I don't get the intended result. Help please!

## UPDATE

To provide context, as somebody pointed out, the problem may lie elsewhere. The regexes are used in the context of this little script which does a few things besides the step that originated this post. I run it on long SRT files obtained from video closed captions. Thanks again for your help.

```
#! perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $filename = $ARGV[0];

open(INPUT_FILE, $filename)
    or die "Couldn't open $filename for reading!";
while (<INPUT_FILE>) {
        my $currentLine = $_;   
        # Remove empty lines and lines that start with digits
        if ($currentLine =~ /^[\s+|\d+]/){
            next;
        }

        # Remove all carriage returns
        $currentLine =~ s/\R$/ /;

        # Convert all letters to lower case
        $currentLine =~ s/([A-Z])/\l$1/g;

        # Capitalize after period <= STEP THAT DOES NOT WORK
        $currentLine =~ s/\.\s([a-z])/\. \u$1/g;        

        print $currentLine;
}
close(INPUT_FILE);
```

Comment: The first regex works for me (Perl 5.22.0 on Mac OS X 10.11.2).  The backslash in front of the `.` in the replacement isn't necessary, but does no harm.

Comment: Both your regexes work for me. The problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: It did not work me yesterday, but all works for me today, centos6.4, perl 5.10.1

Comment: Thanks for testing my regexes. When you say they work for you, how are you testing them? I tried running them in a script and as one-liners, but they don't work. By the way, I'm using perl shipped with Mac OS X 10.10.5 (v5.18.2). Thanks!

Comment: I used this script: `#!/usr/bin/env perl` and `use strict;
use warnings;
my $currentLine = "...so, that's our art. the 4 of us can now have a dialog. we can have a conversation. we can speak to...";
$currentLine =~ s/\.\s([a-z])/\. \u$1/g;
print "$currentLine\n";`  (called `xx.pl`, run using `perl xx.pl`).  With both Perl 5.18.2 (shipped by Apple) and Perl 5.22.0 (built by me), I get the output "`...so, that's our art. The 4 of us can now have a dialog. We can have a conversation. We can speak to...`" with the caps in the correct places AFAICS.

Comment: `/^[\s+|\d+]` matches a line that starts with a whitespace character, a digit, a pipe (`|`) or a plus sign (`+`).   I think you meant `/^(\s*$|\d)/`.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

Use look behind, and capture the pattern and use `\U` for the change the beginning of the string to uppercase

```
$str ="...so, that's our art. the 4 of us can now have a dialog. we can have a conversation. we can speak to...";
$str =~ s/(?<=\w\.\s)(\w)/\U$1/g;
print $str
```

Or else try to `\K` for keep the word by the substitution.

```
$str =~ s/\w\.\s\K(\w)/\U$1/g;
```

Answer (score 0):

One problem is the code:

```
    if ($currentLine =~ /^[\s+|\d+]/){
        next;
    }
```

Contrary to the comment, this ignores lines that start with a space, a digit, a plus or a pipe symbol.  This is probably sending you down the wrong track.  You likely meant to write:

```
    next if /^(\s+$|\d)/;
```

This skips a line if the whole line is spaces, or if the first character is a digit.

You could simplify your loop, and generalize it, with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<>) {
        # Remove empty lines and lines that start with digits. sometimes
        next if /^(\s+$|\d)/;

        # Remove all carriage returns. forever
        s/\R$//;

        # Convert all letters to lower case. always
        s/([A-Z])/\l$1/g;

        # Capitalize after period <=... STEP THAT DOES NOT WORK
        s/\.\s([a-z])/\. \u$1/g;

        print "$_\n";
}
```

When run on itself, the output is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
while (<>) {
        # remove empty lines and lines that start with digits. Sometimes
        next if /^(\s+$|\d)/;
        # remove all carriage returns. Forever
        s/\r$//;
        # convert all letters to lower case. Always
        s/([a-z])/\l$1/g;
        # capitalize after period <=... Step that does not work
        s/\.\s([a-z])/\. \u$1/g;
        print "$_\n";
}
```

Note that for the converted script to work, you'd need to use `/gi` as the modifier (instead of `/g`) on the substitute operations.  There is plenty of room for improvement in this code, still.

One basic way of testing what's going on is to print everything at each step.

```
while (<INPUT_FILE>) {
        print "## $_";
        my $currentLine = $_;   
        # Remove empty lines and lines that start with digits
        if ($currentLine =~ /^[\s+|\d+]/){
            print "#SKIP# $currentLine";
            next;
        }

        # Remove all carriage returns
        $currentLine =~ s/\R$/ /;
        print "#EOL# $currentLine##\n";

        # Convert all letters to lower case
        $currentLine =~ s/([A-Z])/\l$1/g;
        print "#LC# $currentLine##\n";

        # Capitalize after period <= STEP THAT DOES NOT WORK
        $currentLine =~ s/\.\s([a-z])/\. \u$1/g;        
        print "#CAPS# $currentLine##\n";

        print $currentLine;    # Needs a newline!
}
```

This would have told you what was going on, and going wrong.  Note that replacing the generic EOL (`\R`) with a blank means that the output doesn't end with a newline.  That's a bad idea too — and it's why the outputs I generate end with a newline; either the one read from the file, or adding one after that's been removed.

Also, you should avoid ALL_CAPS file handles and use lexical ones — when you need an explicit file handle at all.

```
open my $fh, '<', $filename
    or die "Couldn't open $filename for reading!";
```

Good work on including the file name in the error message (though adding `$!` to report the system error message would be a good idea too).

Answer (score -1):

```
# (char)(char)(char)  (char)(char)(char) Uppercase the 3rd
$str =~ s/(\.)(\s)(\w)/$1$2\U$3/g;
print $str

...so, that's our art. the 4 of us can now have a dialog. we can have a conversation. we can speak to...
...so, that's our art. The 4 of us can now have a dialog. We can have a conversation. We can speak to...
```